# Receiving python code using nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

I'm using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) to run a python script that classifies an image and returns a yes/no if that image is what I'm looking for or not.

Node.js code:

```
app.get('/classify', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: 'src/',
        args: ['--image', '../../images/image.png', 'classifer.xml']
    };

    PythonShell.run('classify_images.py', options, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution 
        console.log('results: %j', results);
    });

    res.send('classify');
});
```

If I run the command as a python script, it works fine but when I run it through node.js, it gives me back all no's.

The python command (in src) is:

```
python classify_images.py --image ../../images/image.png classifer.xml
```

Comment: Some kind of path issue?

Comment: Nope, I printed the args for the nodejs code and the python command and they're the exact same. I can't figure out why the python code says yes (the truth) while nodejs says no. It could be a sync-async issue?

Comment: Node has some security measures that I have encountered while working with a node webkit project. I would bet some security is blocking the python script to be executed properly

Comment: anyway to get around it? I thought using child processes would fix it but it didn't... I'm using opencv for python so could that be why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't put in the right file path - it worked after that.